# Cloud Foundry .cfignore ignore all folders with vendor name

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm using Cloud Foundry to deploy a Bluemix application and I need to ignore a folder named `vendor` which is under the root path of my application and keep the other folder `vendor` under the app folder.

When I browse the app after push, all `vendor` folders were ignored.

I use another case with another folder name `folder__2` and it works fine.

Here is the `.cfignore` file under the app

`/vendor__2/
!/app/vendor__2/
/vendor/
!/app/vendor/
/node_modules/`

Comment: only specify the folders you want it to ignore

Comment: Hi @zerohero, thanx, but  i need to keep the nested folder with name vendor under app folder, i use  the gitignore syntax as described here https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html  and also it works fine for the other folder.